# Supress MDIForm's Menu Shortcut Keys in child form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've an MDI Form with a MenuStrip having several shortcut keys. All works fine but I don't want one thing as explained below:

**When a shortcut key of a menu item in MDIParent form is pressed from a Child Form, the shortcut key still works!!**

I want to have a different implementation of the same shortcut key(of a menu item of MDIParent), when pressed from a child form.

I hope I am able to clarify my problem properly.

Comment: A child should merge its menu with the parent.  Now you got *two* menu items that have the same shortcut.  Clearly you want to avoid confusing the user like this and that's simple to do.  A workaround is overriding ProcessCmdKey() in the child.

Comment: Thanks Hans. Overriding ProcessCmdKey() did worked for me. Thnx Again.